# Regular Expression to extract specified lines

Tags: regex

I have the following comments lines from a workflow software. need to extract some part from 1st line and rest of the comments.

### Here is the sample

```
Nelly Thomas (Approve) 12/27/2012 8:50 PM - 12/27/2012 8:52 PM
(Nelly Thomas) LazyApproval by nelly.thomas@joshworld.local Approved

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
```

Now need to extract it like this.

```
Nelly Thomas 12/27/2012 8:50 PM

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
```

I need a regular expression to achieve this.

Comment: http://whatHaveYouTried.com, and what tools are available to you?

Comment: Your answer will not be "a regular expression".  You still need to write some code.  Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Comment: Andy your comment sounds like your are being sarcastic. Through coding its working I was trying to figure out the regular expression way as the workflow product I am using has "regular expression" conversion feature which i want to use. And please don't under estimate people..these are the forums to help people if you can't don't bother commenting..sit home and relax

Comment: Faiz I am working on a product called "Nintex WorkFlow" which generates Approver Comments like in my question..I've achieved my desired result by writing a webservice but its a dirty hack as I don't want to be dependent on web service anyway so there is a feature in Workflow product where you can apply regular expression to apply on a string...so far i've tried (.*\n|(\(.*.\)) ) and (.*.\))|([0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*)\s([0-9]*:[0-9]*\s(AM|PM)\s-)(\s([0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*)\s([0-9]*:[0-9]*\s(AM|PM)))*|([\n\r])*  ..i am not expert in regex so tried every possible way..and eventually asked help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here you go:

```
var s = "Nelly Thomas (Approve) 12/27/2012 8:50 PM - 12/27/2012 8:52 PM\n\
(Nelly Thomas) LazyApproval by nelly.thomas@joshworld.local Approved\n\
\n\
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, \n\
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book";
s.replace(/(.+)\(.+\)\s((\d\d\/){2}\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d\d\s\w\w)\s-\s.+[\n|\r].+[\n|\r]{2}([^]+)/gi, '$1$2\n\n$4');

//Result: 
"Nelly Thomas 12/27/2012 8:50 PM

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book"
```

It is a working regex, but it's not particularly pretty:

```
# /                   --> Regex start:
# (.+)                --> a word (group #1)
# \(.+\)\s            --> followed by a word in () and a space.
# ((\d\d\/){2}\d{4}\s --> followed by a date and
# \d{1,2}:\d\d\s\w\w) --> time (group #2)
# \s-\s               --> followed by ` - `
# .+                  --> followed by any number of letters or spaces. (The 2nd date)
# [\n|\r]             --> followed by a newline.
# .+                  --> followed by any number of letters or spaces. (The 2nd line)
# [\n|\r]{2}          --> followed by 2 newlines.
# ([^]+)              --> followed by _any_ character, including newlines (group 4)
# /gi                 --> Regex end, (g)lobal flag, case (i)nsensitive flag.
```

Then, output groups `1`, `2` and `4`, with a double newline between `2` and `4`.

So, it's ugly, but it works, as long as the text follows this format:

> W (W) DD\DD\DDDD D(?D):DD LL - W
>   W
>   
>   W

Where `D` is a single digit, `L` is a letter, `W` is any number of words and spaces, excluding newlines and `D(?D)` means one or 2 digits.

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus i am testing it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but its not working somehow..what should I do to make it work

Comment: Hi Cerbrus..First of all thank you so much for the expression you generated ..its working great on gskinner but when I am trying to implement here http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx I am getting "Parse error..Unterminated Set" ...I would appreciate if you can test it in the link i pasted here and let me know...thank you so much once again.

Comment: @user342944: Apparently, that tool doesn't know `[^]`. If you replace `([^]+)` with `((?:.|\n)+)`, it will work. (Make sure `IgnoreCase` and `Multiline` are checked.)

Comment: fantasic...many thanks Cerbrus for awesome solution..you rock man :)

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.